# Cached complex/nested objects and querying them with Greendao Android

Tags: android, json, caching, retrofit, greendao

Ok this is the scenario, I have a complex object like this (see below) and it is downloaded and parsed using Retrofit. I generated the Java class (POJO) using GreenDao and everything is ok while the app is running: retrofit response body is as I want, I insert this `response.body()` to the DB and if I query in other activity this object is retrived by GreenDao with all the attributes setted (is the cached object).

The problem is when I clear all the caches or close the app and open it again, the list of the nested objects is `null` (see the second json below).

How can I solve this? Thanks in Advance

**Json sent from the server**

```
{
    "id" : 91
    "timestamp": 1487786669,
    "groups": [
        {
            "id": "G1",
            "name": "Some name",
            "nextPaymentDate": "2017-06-01",
            "totalAmount": 1000.00,
            "overdraft": false,
            "apoyaT": true
        },
        {
            "id": "G2",
            "name": "Other name",
            "nextPaymentDate": "2017-06-02",
            "totalAmount": 1000.00,
            "overdraft": true,
            "apoyaT": false
        }
    ]
}
```

**Json/JavaObject when the cache is cleared**

```
{
    "id": 91
    "timestamp": 1487786669,
    "groups": null
}
```

**My GreenDao Generator**

```
    /* List Entity ***************************/
    Entity list = schema.addEntity("List_p");
    list.addIntProperty("id").primaryKey();
    list.addLongProperty("timestamp");

    /* Group Entity **************************/
    Entity group = schema.addEntity("Group");
    group.addStringProperty("id").primaryKey();
    group.addStringProperty("name");
    group.addStringProperty("nextPaymentDate");
    group.addDoubleProperty("totalAmount");
    group.addBooleanProperty("overdraft");
    group.addBooleanProperty("apoyaT");

    Property listId =  group.addLongProperty("listId").getProperty();
    list.addToMany(group, listId, "groups");
```

Comment: How are you assigning the values to the JSON object?

Comment: Hey! I already solved this. I am going to post the solution these days. Thx btw